# Home/Index defaulting to login page

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have just implemented the following in my home controller:

```
<Authorize(Roles:="Administrator")> _
<Authorize(Roles:="Manager")> _
<Authorize(Roles:="General")> _
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

But even when I have logged in either going to /Home/Index or when it is called by @RenderBody returns the login page and the following url: /Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f

I have not changed any of my routing in the Global file either. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I have subsequently found out that anything I add these

```
<Authorize(Roles:="Administrator")> _
```

tags to will constantly ask me for the password?

My ViewStart too:

```
@Code

Dim r = Roles.GetRolesForUser()

If r.Contains("Administrator") Then
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.vbhtml"
ElseIf r.Contains("Manager") Then
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ManagerLayout.vbhtml"
ElseIf r.Contains("General") Then
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GeneralLayout.vbhtml"
Else
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NoUserLayout.vbhtml"
End If

End Code
```

Comment: Are you logged in as a user with appropriate permissions?  ie correct role assignment?

Comment: Yeah I am. I know this too because I define certain master view layouts for different and the administrator one shows correctly when I am logged in as an administrator but does not authorize as above.

Comment: Just redefined roles but still nothing :( And roles are definitely working as can see from the ViewStart above forwarding correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than 3 separate attributes, try combining them into one, like:

```
<Authorize(Roles:="General,Manager,Administrator")>
```

Comment: Solves the problem. Think it can't be stacked